# compressing a folder by taking the whole data instead of one file at a time

Tags: algorithm, compression

I'm working on a project which its goal is to create a compression software from zero like gzip using the DEFLATE algorithm and I ran into a puzzling question while planning it.
is it possible to compress a folder and its files by taking the data as it is all at one and make it one compressed file and then in the decompression divide it back to the files the folder had?
is it even beneficial for compression?
also if it exists in a current software what is it?

Answer (score 0):

That is what is normally done on Unixish systems, first serializing the folder into a tar file, and then compressing that. There is an advantage if adjacent files have common strings, which in fact is the case for, for example, source code directories.

Comment: Is this method efficient in windows too? or do windows have their own way of doing it that works better for it?

Comment: The potential for that advantage is always there, and has nothing to do with the operating system. 7z and rar have a solid-archive option that does this. Or you can use tar and gzip on Windows system as well.